# Is this sentence in line with pronoun of complement subject?

Tags: pronouns, subject-complement, object-complements

I read online that subject pronoun are used for subject complement. As such, is the following sentence correct? "He seems to be I" or should it end with object case? And why?

Comment: What on earth does _He seems to be I_ mean?

Comment: It is hypothetical, I am subject complement, I just want to know if using "I" is correct or not as "to be" is not transferring the action to any object. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: When announcing your own arrival, "It is I" is strictly correct, but sounds absurdly formal. In real life, most people would say "It's me".